# No image display on listView

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, listview

I'm trying to retrieve the image from `MySQL` and display it to `listView` but no success. Have I missed anything?

This is what I have tried.

**Table staff_benefit**

[image]

```
public void BuildEditStaffList(final String id)
    {
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.7/Android/CRUD/staffRetrieve.php?id="+id);


                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;
                showList();
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }

     protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        details= jsonObj.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<details.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = details.getJSONObject(i);
            String type = c.getString(Config.TAG_TYPE);
            String description = c.getString(Config.TAG_DESCRIPTION);
            String amount=c.getString(Config.TAG_AMOUNT);
            String image=c.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE);
            byte[] data = Base64.decode(image, 0);
            Bitmap b =BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b);
            int ID=c.getInt(Config.TAG_ID);
            //v.setImageBitmap(b);
            HashMap<String,Object> info = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            info.put(Config.TAG_TYPE, type);
            info.put(Config.TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
            info.put(Config.TAG_AMOUNT,amount);
            info.put(Config.TAG_IMAGE,d);
            info.put(Config.TAG_ID,ID+"");
            StaffDetails.add(info);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(),StaffDetails, R.layout.retrieve_staff,
                new String[]{Config.TAG_IMAGE,Config.TAG_TYPE,Config.TAG_AMOUNT,Config.TAG_DESCRIPTION},
                new int[]{R.id.image,R.id.type,R.id.amount,R.id.description}
        );

        listViewEdit.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**staffRetrieve.php**

```
<?php
  define('HOST','127.0.0.1:3307');
  define('USER','root');
  define('PASS','');
  define('DB','androiddb');

  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('unable to connect');

  $tws = $_GET['id'];

 $sql = "select * from staff_benefit WHERE ts_id= '". $tws."' ";

  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  $result=array();

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      array_push($result,array('id'=>$row[0],'type'=>$row[1],'amount'=>$row[2],'description'=>$row[3],'image'=>$row[4],
      'ts_id'=>$row[5]));
  }

 echo (json_encode(array("result"=>$result)));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Text get displayed but not for image

**ListView**

[image]

Image should be shown in the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited

Create Staff object first.

```
public class Staff {
    private int id;
    private String image;
    private String type;
    private String amount;
    private String description;

    public Staff(int id, String type, String description, String amount, String image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.image = image;
        this.type = type;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Here is the `Adapter.class`

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Staff> {
    Activity context;
    List<Staff> staffs;
    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;
        public TextView type;
        public TextView amount;
        public TextView description;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return staffs.size();
    }
    public Adapter(Activity context, List<Staff> staffs) {
        super(context, R.layout.retrieve_staff, staffs);
        this.context = context;
        this.staffs = staffs;
    }

    @Override
    public Staff getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            ViewHolder v = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.retrieve_staff, null);
            v.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            v.amount = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            v.type = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            v.description = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            convertView.setTag(v);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        Log.v("TEST",staffs.get(position).getImage());
        byte[] data = Base64.decode(staffs.get(position).getImage(), 0);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),b);
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(d);
        holder.amount.setText(staffs.get(position).getAmount());
        holder.type.setText(staffs.get(position).getType());
        holder.description.setText(staffs.get(position).getDescription());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and this is the `showList()` method

```
protected void showList(){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            details= jsonObj.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_RESULTS);

            for(int i=0;i<details.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = details.getJSONObject(i);
                String type = c.getString(Config.TAG_TYPE);
                String description = c.getString(Config.TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                String amount=c.getString(Config.TAG_AMOUNT);
                String image=c.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE);
                Staff staff = new Staff(ID,type,description,amount,image);
                staffs.add(staff);
            }

            Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(),staffs);
            listViewEdit.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response..Am I doing in the correct way ? No image get displayed and I get this in log   `E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@42ea2938: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: If I remove `Drawable d', I get this `E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)`

Comment: I have tested the codes. It went fine. I used `imageView.setImageDrawable(d)` to set image to ImageView. At which line did the exception occur?

Comment: can you see my post again, just edited. I want it display on listView

Comment: I think you should use a CustomAdapter for listview instead of using `SimpleAdapter`.

Comment: Can you provide some examples to me ?

Comment: Try using setImageBitmap and put that bitmap inside HashMap while passing to adapter constructor.

Comment: @Kris where should I use setImageBitmap

Comment: @YeMinHtut thanks..I trying your answer now. So no need to use HashMap ?

Comment: @JohnJoe You don't need you use HashMap anymore.

Comment: @JohnJoe From the json object.

Comment: Create `List<Staff> staffs = new ArrayList()` globally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99573/discussion-between-john-joe-and-ye-min-htut).

Comment: @YeMinHtut please reply me when you are free...I still have a lot of problem need your help..thanks